# Trying to call multiple functions under the SerialPort_DataReceived event

Tags: vb.net, function, serial-port

**What I'm trying to do:** (Big wall of text so I labeled each part to make it easier to read)

Hello, I'm making an application in VS 2010, for an RFID controlled magnetic door lock circuit, which Receives RFID tag ID over the serial port, authenticate it from the database (SQL server 2005), sends a signal to the circuit over the serial port, and saves the current time and ID into a database.

The microcontroller circuit I designed works as follows : Read Tag ID from RFID module > send Tag ID to PC via serial port upon pressing a button on the circuit > receive a string of data, either "ACCEPTED" or "REJECTED" > Turn on a red LED or deactivate magnetic lock depending on received data string.

**What I did:**

I divided the above tasks into functions - CheckValidate() to authenticate ID from DB, SendData() to send data string to my circuit, Intermediate() to fetch the ID's corresponding Name from DB and SaveData() to save the ID, Name and Current Time into the DB.

**The problem:**

They each work perfectly when I execute them separately, but I need them to execute one after the other under one event, the SerialPort_DataReceived event. I tried calling all functions one after the other under the DataReceived event's sub. And I tried calling the first function under the DataReceived event and then nested the other functions in each other. Neither work, the first function executes and my application stops responding.

**My Full Code:**

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1
    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection
    Dim Chars(11) As Char
    Dim CharsCnt As Integer
    Dim currtime As String
    Dim savename As String

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        CharsCnt += SerialPort1.Read(Chars, CharsCnt, Chars.Length - CharsCnt)
        If CharsCnt = Chars.Length Then
            Me.Invoke(New SetReceivedText(AddressOf SetText))
            CharsCnt = 0
        End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub SetReceivedText()

Private Sub SetText()
        CheckValidate()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckValidate()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = sqlcon

        If (sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            sqlcon.Open()
        End If

        cmd.CommandText = "select Name from masterdata where ID = '" & Chars & "'"

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
            TextBox2.Text = "REJECTED"
            dt.Dispose()
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "ACCEPTED"
        End If

        sqlcon.Close()

        SendData()
End Sub

Private Sub SendData()

        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            SerialPort1.Close()
        End If

        Using com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM2")
            com1.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        End Using

        If TextBox2.Text = "ACCEPTED" Then
            Intermediate()
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub Intermediate()
        TextBox1.Text = Chars

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = sqlcon

        cmd.CommandText = "select Name from masterdata where ID = '" & Chars & "'"

        If (sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            sqlcon.Open()
        End If

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        sqlcon.Close()

        SaveData()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
        currtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
        savename = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        If (sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            sqlcon.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Connection = sqlcon

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into logdata values('" & Chars & "','" & savename & "','" & currtime & "')"

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)

        sqlcon.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
        Next s
        Label1.Text = "All COM ports are closed."

        sqlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;User ID=TAS; password = TAS123; database=secure"
        sqlcon.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                SerialPort1.Close()
            End If

            If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Port.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            Else
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.PortName = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
                SerialPort1.Open()
                Label1.Text = "'" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "' COM port is Open"
            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Could not open Port, please try again!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

**When what I want to do works:** (Executed each function individually using buttons)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SendData()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If TextBox2.Text = "ACCEPTED" Then
            Intermediate()
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        SaveData()
End Sub
```

Any help on how I could get all functions executed under the one DataRecieved event would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution, the problem was here:

```
Using com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM2")
     com1.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
End Using
```

Removed the *Using* statement and left the port on. Used just:

```
SerialPort1.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
```